# How can I evaluate a String to double where String is double (a+b)

Tags: java

```
String num = "9+9";
double answer = Double.parseDouble(num);
```

I understand I could use something called [ScriptEngineManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52900739/string-to-double-a-b). I copied that code, and was given the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.script.ScriptEngine.eval(String)" because "engine" is null
    at WritingClasses.Test.EvalMath(Test.java:25)
    at WritingClasses.Test.main(Test.java:11)
```

Comment: parse it yourself maybe, use regex to split numbers and variables do the calculation on your own

Comment: See also: [*How to use Nashorn in Java 15 and later?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65265629/642706) and [*Nashorn removal: GraalVM to the rescue!*](https://medium.com/graalvm/nashorn-removal-graalvm-to-the-rescue-d4da3605b6cb)